# How many elements of order 5 are there in a group of order 45?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**The Problem:**

As the title asks: How many elements of order $5$ are there in a group of order $45$?

**My Approach:**

Let $G$ be a group of order $45$.

My first thought is to hit it with Sylow's Theorems, which tells me that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $5$ (call it $N$) and a normal subgroup of order $9$. Clearly $4$ out of the $5$ elements in $N$ must be of order $5$ (since they must divide the order of $N$); and clearly none of these elements are in the normal subgroup of order $9$.

So, this means $G$ has at least $4$ elements of order $5$. Are there any more, though? The only thing I can think of is to investigate the possibility of a subgroup of order 15... but how would I know if $G$ has such a subgroup? And, if it did, how would I know whether it intersects $N$ trivially?

Comment: Why does Sylow tell you that there is a normal subgroup of order $5$?  Remember, all the Sylow $p-$ groups are conjugate so this would mean that there was a unique Sylow $5-$ group.  Note:  you are correct in this case, but I think it needs a clearer argument.

Comment: A subgroup of order $15$ is the product of the subgroup of order $5$ and a subgroup of order $3$, contained in the $3$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: @lulu: the number of $5$-Sylow subgroups is congruent to $1\bmod 5$ and it is a divisor of $9$.

Comment: @Bernard Are you saying that there is a subgroup of order 15 contained in a subgroup of order 9?

Comment: I didn't check in detail, but I'd think that we might have a semi-direct product of the subgroup of order $5$ and a subgroup of order $3$ contained in the  $3$-Sylow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already did 70% of the work:

Let $G$ be of order $45 = 5\cdot 3^2$. By Sylow's second theorem, the number of 5-sylow-groups $n_5$ must be either 1, 3, or 9.  Out of those choices, only $n_5=1\equiv 1$ modulo 5. Therefore, only *one* subgroup of order 5 exists (normality isn't even important here).

Now note that every possible element of order five generates a subgroup of order five (in which it must be contained).  I'm confident you can take it from here. `:-)`

Comment: So, if $x \in G$ with $|x| = 5$, then $\langle x \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $|\langle x \rangle| = 5$. Since $|\langle x \rangle| = 5$, it must be conjugate to $N$; but since there's only one Sylow 5-subgroup (i.e., $N$), it must be that $\langle x \rangle = N$. Therefore, there must be exactly 4 elements of order 5 in $G$. Right?

Comment: That is correct, although the fact that every Sylow-p-groups are conjugate isn't even necessary: _every_ group of order five is, by definition, a Sylow-5-subgroup of $G$. Therefore, given we only have one Sylow-5-subgroup, this is precisely what $\langle x \rangle$ must be.